# Swift Playground WebView won't display local images

Tags: swift, ipad, webview, wkwebview, swift-playground

I am working on a Switft Playground and am trying to get a WebView to display full HTML5 content, including images. At the moment, I am able to get a WebView to display full HTML5 content if it comes from the web, but only text if it is being loaded locally, from within the Playground.

This is the code from my Sources:

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

import Foundation
import UIKit

public class MyWebKitViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

public override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

public func loadLocalHtml(filename: String) {
    let possiblePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "html")
    if let path = possiblePath {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)}
}
}
```

And this is this is the code that I'm using to call the loadLocalHtml function:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

//Set current Playground View
let vc = MyWebKitViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc

vc.loadLocalHtml(filename: "testing")
```

I've tried solutions others have posted to similar sounding issues here, but haven't had success. In some instances, I get a WebView that just displays a white background but no content at all. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Have you tried an actual single view app? Maybe even one with internet access? (I don't know if anything matters, but you've specified playgrounds *and* 'WebKit'.) Just trying to rule out things.

Comment: I haven't done a single view app, but I have done the dual view with WKWebView embedded within a Playground. It works great with content coming from the Internet. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Should be something like this but I don't get it. Looks like Swift Playgrounds has a different way to manage resources. In Xcode Playground your code works as expected

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667))
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html") {
    let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image1", withExtension: "png", subdirectory: "images/")
    webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: imageURL!)
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = webView
```

Should you find a way, please answer :]